# Bokeh: how to add legend to patches glyph with GeoJSONDataSource and CategoricalColorMapper?

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to add a legend to a Bokeh patches figure, but I end up with only one legend item (and with the wrong label).

I have a shape file with polygons. Each polygon has an attribute called 'category', which can take the values 'A', 'B, 'C', 'D' and 'E'. I convert the shape file to geojson and subsequently create a Bokeh patches figure, using CategoricalColorMapper to add a colour to each polygon depending on the 'category' it is in. Now I want the legend to show the five category options and their respective colours.

Here's my code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook, output_file, export_png
from bokeh.models import GeoJSONDataSource, CategoricalColorMapper, Legend, LegendItem
from bokeh.plotting import figure, reset_output
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap
import selenium
import numpy as np

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file("test.shp")
gdf_json = gdf.to_json()
source_shape = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson=gdf_json)

cmap = CategoricalColorMapper(palette=["black", "purple", "pink", "brown", "blue"], factors=['A','B','C','D', 'E'])

p = figure(height=500, match_aspect=True,
    h_symmetry=False, v_symmetry=False, min_border=0)

p.patches('xs', 'ys', source=source_shape, fill_color={'field': 'category', 'transform': cmap},
             line_color='black', line_width=0.5, legend='category')
export_png(p, filename="map.png")
```

However, the output I get is as follows:
[map.png output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYPtJ.png)

The legend shows only one item, with the label 'category' rather than the actual category names. How can I fix this such that the legend shows all 5 categories with their labels (A,B,C,D,E)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code does what you want, however, I think it could be easier to manipulate the `GeoDataFrame` directly instead of converting to `JSON`. This code is compatible with Bokeh v1.0.4.

```
from bokeh.models import GeoJSONDataSource, CategoricalColorMapper
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.io import export_png
import geopandas as gpd
import random
import json

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file("Judete/Judete.shp")
gdf_json = gdf.to_json()
gjson = json.loads(gdf_json)

categories = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
for item in gjson['features']:
    item['properties']['category'] = random.choice(categories)

source_shapes = {}
for category in categories:
    source_shapes[category] = {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": []}

for item in gjson['features']:
    source_shapes[item['properties']['category']]['features'].append(item)

p = figure(match_aspect = True, min_border = 0,
           h_symmetry = False, v_symmetry = False,
           x_axis_location = None, y_axis_location = None)

cmap = CategoricalColorMapper(palette = ["orange", "purple", "pink", "brown", "blue"], 
                              factors = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
for category in categories:
    source_shape = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson = json.dumps(source_shapes[category]))
    p.patches('xs', 'ys', fill_color = {'field': 'category', 'transform': cmap},
                          line_color = 'black', line_width = 0.5,
                          legend = category, source = source_shape,)
p.legend.click_policy = 'hide'
show(p) # export_png(p, filename = "map.png")
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the legend is not currently working with GeoJSONDataSource as there is an open issue [Legend not working with GeoJSONDataSource #5904](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5904) that is still unresolved.